# Microsoft Graph API to get list of AAD groups owned by a user

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

In our application, we need to get the list of AAD groups that a user is owner of. Is there any Microsoft Graph API to do the same?

If an API is not there, what is another efficient way to do the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this MS graph api to do that: [List ownedObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-ownedobjects?view=graph-rest-1.0), it gets the list of directory objects that are owned by the user.

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{User Object ID}/ownedObjects`

[image]

If you just want to get the group name and group type, you can use `$select`,

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{User Object ID}/ownedObjects?$select=displayName,groupTypes`

[image]

Comment: Should note the voted answer here does not filter out non-groups. Applications owned by user will still appear in the response.

Answer (score 1):

As Answered by @Joy Wang You could use [List ownedObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-ownedobjects?view=graph-rest-1.0) graph API to do that where it gets the list of directory objects that are owned by the user.

But as the question is about getting the list of AAD groups that a user is owner of, you can use the below graph API where it gets the list of directory objects with *odata.type* as **microsoft.graph.group**:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{User Object ID}/ownedObjects/microsoft.graph.group
```

And if you just want to get the group name and group ID, you can use $select,

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{User Object ID}/ownedObjects/microsoft.graph.group?$select=displayName,id
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this! For reference, how would you find this pattern in the documentation? I have been searching for a way to list owned applications (microsoft.graph.application) for longer than I want to admit, and even now that I know the answer, I don't know how I would have found this without your answer.

Comment: @PerStolpe Glad that you found my response helpful and I agree, it's not called out in the official documentation. Even it took me a while to identify this pattern while I was working on similar case for my application. Hence, thought to put this out as an answer here as it might help someone in future. :)